# PostgreSQL - Can't Search (LIKE and ILIKE) a column with 'macaddr' type

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I am trying to search my DB for a Mac address...and ran into a bunch of trouble.

```
SELECT

    devices.mac AS dev_mac

WHERE devices.mac LIKE '00:00:11:00:99:1B'
```

I have also tried `CAST(devices.mac AS varchar) AS dev_mac` to `CAST` as varchar and still unable to perform a search.

I have tried `ILIKE` as well. And nothing seems to work.

Have also tried to replace the `:`, nothing.

---

Keep getting errors like so:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: macaddr ~~ unknown
ERROR:  operator does not exist: macaddr ~~* unknown
```

---

What am I doing wrong? How do I properly search the `macaddr` data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you `WHERE` clause, you need to `CAST` the `macaddr` field to `varchar`, then you can use any string comparison operator on it (`LIKE`,  `=`, ...).

Like :

```
SELECT mac 
FROM devices
WHERE CAST(mac as varchar) LIKE '00:00:11:00:99:1B'
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem? If you cast it to `VARCHAR` it works right away:

```
create table m1 (
  id int,
  mac1 macaddr
);

insert into m1 (id, mac1) values (1, '08:00:2b:01:02:03');
insert into m1 (id, mac1) values (2, '08:00:2b:01:02:04');

select id, cast(mac1 as varchar) 
from m1 
where cast(mac1 as varchar) like '%4'
```

Result:

```
id           mac1             
------------------------------
2            08:00:2b:01:02:04
```